Gnat Pro linker skips files that aren't being included
I am using Gnat Pro/Gnat Studio with a project that uses C++ but calls an Ada library. I am using Boost Tests in the C++ code, which according to this example is split into multiple .cpp files which #include the boost unit_test file. Thus, the .cpp files with the Boost tests are not included in the main file of the project, because Boost is handling that execution.
However, it appears that Gnat Pro is doing some kind of optimization where the files are being compiled into .o object files, but those object files are skipped over in the linker. Is there some kind of flag or options in Gnat Pro that can tell it to link everything?
Thanks,
Nathan
EDIT: Here is my example. Note that there may be some minor errors because I had to transcribe by hand from the closed system.
main.cpp:
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TEST
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>

extern void test();

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char*envp[])
{
   //test(); //This forces Test2.o to get linked. Commenting it out makes the test tree empty
   return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(&init_unit_test, argc, argv);
}

Test2.cpp:
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>
void test(){
   std::cout << "help" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUIT(MyTest)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TEST1)
{
   std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TEST2)
{
   std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

default.gpr:
with "lib_boost.gpr";

project Default is

   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.cpp");
   for Languages use ("C++");

   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches("c++") use
         ("-v","-isystem" & lib_boost.INCLUDE_DIR,
         "-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK");

   package Linker is
      for Default_Switches("c++") use lib_boost.OS_LIBS;
   end Linker;

   package Ide is
      for Vcs_Kind use "git";
   end Ide;

end Default;

lib_boost.gpr:
abstract project lib_boost is
   HOME := External("HOME", "~/");
   ROOT_DIR := external("BOOST_DIR", HOME & "/boost/1.67.0/gcc8.3.1/rhel64/");
   INCLUDE_DIR := ROOT_DIR & "include";
   LIB_DIR := ROOT_DIR & "lib";
   LIB_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK := "boost_unit_test_framework";

   OS_LIBS := (
       "-L" & LIB_DIR,
       "-l" & LIB_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK
       );

   package Install is
       for Artifacts ("bin") use (
           ROOT_DIR & "/" & LIB_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK & ".*"
           );
   end Install;
end lib_boost;

EDIT2: Here's a modified version of Test2.cpp with manual registration. The result is the same, the test tree is empty. init_unit_test doesn't seem to be run at all.
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::unit_test;
void test(){
   std::cout << "help" << std::endl;
}

void TEST1()
{
   std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;
}

void TEST2()
{
   std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
}

static test_suite* init_unit_test(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   test(); //Doesn't print anything, suggesting this function isn't being used
   test_suite* MyTest = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("MyTest");
   MyTest->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(TEST1));
   MyTest->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(TEST2));
   framework::master_test_suite().add(MyTest);
   return 0;
}


What is the objective? Exactly what observable difference would there be if the object files are actually unused? Most likely there's something else missing, like the registration of tests, which may be governed by a preprocessor definition see e g  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html

@sehe The observable difference is that without the object files then no boost test can be run, it lists the test tree as empty. If I modify the GPR file to force one of the object files to get linked, then the test tree shows the tests of that specific CPP file and nothing else.

@sehe I can confirm I do include #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE and #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>. That's not the source of the issue

I get the impression that something else is off. To me, if the tests register themselves, they cannot possibly be optimized out. So it seems that they don't, which suggests a preprocessor symbol causes it to conditionally compile away. Perhaps you can make a simple self-contained example (max 10 lines of CMakeLists.txt, max 3x10 lines of C++ TUs?)

@sehe I wish I could provide an example but it seems that writing an example in Visual Studio doesn't give the same problem, but I don't have gnat pro installed on this computer to verify. The original code is on a closed system. But I can try to install it here at some point

@sehe I included my example GNAT pro code that you can check and confirm the issue I'm dealing with

Good start. Where's init_unit_test - that's the crucial bit really (compare https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/link_references/link_boost_test_no_main.html)

If it was supposed to be init_unit_test_suite that might indicate that you're trying to use the obsolete registration variant, which (for example) cannot work with shared libraries, see "In the shared-library usage variant, it is not possible to use the obsolete initialization function"

For now, I'm not getting much luck with GNAT community: https://i.imgur.com/XYUZhEZ.png

It appears that the code I am using doesn't have a init_unit_test defined anywhere, and is using some default implementation imported from Boost. I'll have to see if implementing it will fix the problem

I will also add that the code of the full system I am using (as opposed to this simple example) uses BOOST_TEST_MAIN instead of BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN, and uses auto registration instead of manual registration. I might try to see if I can update the example to be more accurate @sehe

Btw idk a lot of how to set up Gnat pro but I know that the command to compile a project is gprbuild -P default.gpr

Wow, @NathanGoedeke, changing the BOOST_TEST[_NO]_MAIN really alters the essence of the situation. I'll await a more accurate sample then. By the way, this is with the default main and autoregistration indeed: https://gist.github.com/sehe/8144b8af4176ee88f78bf17632606bb7?permalink_comment_id=5015303#gistcomment-5015303

@sehe I changed the code to be exactly the way it is in your gist (just commenting out everything in main.cpp except the #define BOST_TEST_MODULE TEST and #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>) and the test tree was empty. I did not get the same results as you did

@sehe I edited my question to add an alternate version of Test2.cpp that is supposed to use manual registration, but it doesn't seem to work at all

Did you use a gcc compiler with the arguments fed in mimicking the gpr file, and not actually using gnat pro? That's why I phrased the question the way I did, because I feel that gnat pro specifically is doing something that messes up the registration
